# Is there a reiser4 patched kernel available somwhere?

Tags: 11.04, kernel, filesystem, patch, reiserfs

I'd like to experiment with this filesystem. I don't want to argue the why and wherefores I was just wondering if a pre patched kernel was available anywhere?

Comment: jeez is this too l33t for the ubuntu crowd or something? my second tumbleweed badge on stackexchange FGS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to patch your own source tree and build your custom kernel.
As of now, libaal-1.0.5.tar.gz, reiser4-for-2.6.32.patch, and reiser4progs-1.0.7.tar.gz is needed.
Works like a charm.